# A construction of a triangle mapping with a homothety

Tags: euclidean-geometry, geometric-construction

Given an acute triangle $ABC$ draw a triangle $PQR$ such that $AB=2PQ,BC=2QR,CA=2RP$, and the lines $PQ,QR,RP$ pass through $A,B,C$ respectively. Note $A,B,C,P,Q,R$ are distinct.

This is a problem from the Middle European Mathematical Olympiad 2013. I tried to locate the homothetic center mapping the triangles $ABC$ and $PQR$ into each other. I suspected it could be the incenter, but no conclusive evidence. It could be a variable point. But in general I cannot think anything of this problem. Can someone help? Thanks.

Comment: A homothety from $\triangle ABC$ to $\triangle PQR$ requires a center common to lines $\overleftrightarrow{AP}$, $\overleftrightarrow{BQ}$, $\overleftrightarrow{CR}$. But these are exactly the lines $\overleftrightarrow{PQ}$, $\overleftrightarrow{QR}$, $\overleftrightarrow{RP}$ containing the sides of $\triangle PQR$; there is no common point.

Comment: For those interested: The official solution to this problem, with an appearance from the [Brocard point](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Brocard_points), is [here](http://memo2013.mik.uni-pannon.hu/images/comprofiler/problems_individual/solutions.pdf). See Problem T-5.

Answer (score 0):

[image]

solution:

make high $CD \perp  AB$,since it is acute triangle, $D$ will fall on $AB$.  $EC \perp CB,$  circle C @$r=CB$, cross $EC$ at $E$, make $EF \perp EC$, extend $CA$, cross $ FE $ at $F$, circle B @$r=BA$, cross line $CB$ at $G$, connect $BF$, make $GH$//$BF$, cross $EF$ at $H$,connect $CH$, make it's midpoint $ M $, circle M@$r=MH$, cross $CG$ at $N$, connect $HN$, make it's midpoint $S$,,circle H @r=HS, cross circle $M$ at $T$, connect $CT$, circle C@$r=CB$, cross $CT$ at $B'$,circle C @$r=CA$, cross $CB$ at $H$, cross $CT$ at $U$,make $\angle B'CA$  bisector $CV$, cross circle $CA$ at $V$, circle V@$r=VH$, cross circle $CA$ at $A'$, connect $A'B'$, make $RB$//$A'B'$, cross $CT$ at $R$, connect $A'C$,make $AQ$//$A'C$, cross $CT$ at $Q$, cross $BR$ at $P, \triangle PQR $ is the solution.

to proof this method, put $ECB$ on $yOx$, then set $B(a,0),A(b\cos{C},b\sin{C})$

let $B'(a\cos{\alpha},b\sin{\alpha}),R(x_1,y_1),Q(x_2,y_2)$, note $x_1-x_2=\dfrac{a\cos{\alpha}}{2}, ab\sin{C}=ch_c,c^2=a^2+b^2-2ab\cos{C}$

more comments : this solution always work when high foot fall on the side. so it is mean for any triangle we can find the solution no matter if acute or not. the standard solution is conservative.